# If x is irrational, then 10x is irrational proof

Tags: proof-verification, irrational-numbers

Proof by contrapositive. Find mistakes in my proof if there are any.

Suppose $10x$ is rational, then $10x = p/q$, for some integers $p$ and $q$, where $q$ does not equal 0. So, $x = p/(10q)$, where $p$ and $10q$ are integers and $10q$ does not equal $0$. So $x$ is rational. We proved the contrapositive so the claim is true.

my question is do I need to state that $p$ and $10$ are co-prime for this proof to be valid? Is this already a valid proof?

Comment: It is a valid proof as written: a rational number is simply $a/b$ for any integers $a,b$, it doesn't matter if they have common factors. You might be thinking of having them co-prime from doing similar proofs (like the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$), but in those cases this is required because the argument requires some control over the divisibility properties of the numbers involved (say to be able to derive a contradiction). Here there is no requirement like that.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is correct and, no, you don't need to prove that $p$ and $10$ are co-prime. And that's a good thing, since they might fail to be co-prime! That's what would happen if, say, $x=\frac27$.